# C - vsprintf , va_list

Tags: c, linux

i have write this code but i'm not sure that it's ok.

```
size_t sendHeaders(int fd, int seconds, const char* header1, ...) {
    size_t len = 0;
    char *retbuf;
    va_list args;
    const char* hdr;
    if (header1 == NULL)
        common_setErrorCode(ERROR);
    return ERROR;
    len = strlen(header1);
    va_start(args, header1);
    while ((hdr=va_arg(args,char *))!=NULL)
        len += strlen(hdr);
    va_end(args);
    retbuf = malloc(len + 1);
    if (retbuf == NULL)
        common_setErrorCode(ERROR);
    return ERROR;
    (void) strcpy(retbuf, header1);
    va_start(args, header1);
    while ((hdr=va_arg(args,char *))!= NULL)
        (void) strcat(retbuf, hdr);
    va_end(args);
    char buffer[255] = { 0, };
    vsprintf(buffer, hdr, args);
    if (BUFSIZ == 0) {
        common_setErrorCode(ERROR);
        return ERROR;
    }
    write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    common_setErrorCode(SUCCESS);
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

but the problem is that vsprintf() doesn't print anythings to console. And i would know if the code is ok (personally i think that it's ok). 
Regards

Comment: This will never get past `return ERROR;`.

Comment: Either one of the two you failed to include in the `{}` that should always follow an `if`, `while`, or `for`. ;-)

Comment: This code does not look correct because it calls `vsprintf` with concatenated headers as "format", and unconcatenated headers as "arguments". If you just need to concatenate the headers, why bother with calling `vsprintf`? You should omit the call to `vsprintf` and call `write(fd, hdr, len)`.

Comment: Please cook your code down to a MCVE before asking here, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Of course `vsprintf()` doesn't print to the console, that's not its purpose. It just builds the string, which you must then write to the console yourself if that's what you want. Luckily you do that. :) The problem is probably that `stdout` is line-buffered, assuming `fd` is the console.

Also, you need to check that the I/O calls don't fail.

Also, as pointed out by Biffen, you have a bare `return` in the code, which will of course exit the function at that point.

Single-step through the function in a debugger.